# Given an Ellipse, how Do You Calculate the Length of Chords passing through a given point on the minor axis.

Tags: geometry

Given a point on the minor axis of an ellipse (that is not the centre) how do you calculate the length of each chord (in rotation) passing through this point.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Notice that some have voted to close your question. This is because you have not included in your question your own thoughts on the problem, the steps you have tried and where you are stuck. You should edit your question to include this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** There is an equation for a line given its $x$ and $y$-intercepts. The angle at which the line crosses the axes can also be found from the intercepts. Together with the equation of the ellipse, one should be able to find the coordinates of $A$ and $C$ in the diagram and the distance between them. There are other ways to solve this problem (perhaps use the reflective property of an ellipse), but this is one approach which should lead to a solution.

[image: Chord of ellipse]

Comment: What software did you use to create the graph?  It looks very nice.

Comment: @irchans  https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 0):

Passing by a point on the minor axis is nothing special so I'll answer for a general line of parametric equations

$$\begin{cases}x=x_0+\alpha t,\\y=y_0+\beta t\end{cases},$$ and a general ellipse

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dx+2ey+f.$$

Plug the first in the second, and you get a quadratic equation in $t$:

$$ax_0^2+2bx_0y_0+cy_0^2+2dx_0+2ey_0+f+2(a\alpha x_0+b\beta x_0+b\alpha y_0+c\beta y_0+d\alpha+e\beta)+(a\alpha^2+2b\alpha\beta+c\beta^2)t^2.$$